# Simulate Press Key Y Shell Linux

Tags: linux, shell, keyboard

I have a binary program in the linux shell where it asks a question whether to continue or not. I need to run it manually because of that question. It would be possible to automate, with a simulation of keyboard pressing always answering "Yes / Y" and then giving an "Enter"?

```
Example:

command | Y and ENTER
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `yes | <your command>` ([`man yes`](https://ss64.com/bash/yes.html))

Comment: Works fine!!! Thanks!!!  Is there anything to simulate "No / N"?

Comment: Read the man page I gave you: `yes no` or `yes n`

Comment: It worked !!!!! If you can put it in answer so I can mark it as resolved! Thanks again!

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Congratulations jww !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `yes` and pipe that to your command.

```
yes | <your command>
```

`yes` continuously prints 'y' and a newline (<kbd>Enter</kbd>, if you like). It was designed exactly for such kind of problems as you have.

It can also be used to print anything else in that way. Just supply the string you want as an argument, e.g. `yes no` to print 'no' continuously.

Type [`man yes`](https://ss64.com/bash/yes.html) to see the man page for `yes`.